# Pandas DF Column Data Splitting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame (shown below)

```
Room_ID        Chamber_ID        Floor_Name
-----------  ------------     ------------------------ 
111,222                 9 
111                     9 
None                    1 
111,222,333             1
```

And a function

```
def GetFloorName(Room_ID, Chamber_ID):
   THis Will Return the Floor_Name
```

This data in DF has to be pushed in the function one by one in for each row like in row one it will

````
the Data is 111,222 in Room_ID and 9 in Chamber_id```
````

So the function call should be like

```
    GetFloorName(111,9) which will return a Value (For Eg: X)
    GetFloorName(222,9) which will return a Value (For Eg: Y)
```

Now both these values need to updates in `Floor_Name` separated by comma like done below:

Expected Output DF

```
Room_ID        Chamber_ID        Floor_Name
-----------  ------------     ------------------------ 
111,222                 9         X,Y
111                     9 
None                    1 
111,222,333             1
```

How to do this using Pandas?

Comment: also post the dictionary where you are looking up for the floor name

Comment: its a SQL Call That Will get Data From DataBase

Comment: does this work: `df.Room_ID.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ','.join([d[i] for i in x]))` assuming `d={'111':'X','222':'Y','333':'Z'}`

Comment: I Need to Pass Both the Values i.e Room_ID and Chamber_ID to get the Floor Name Thats Stored in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to df.appy()

```
# Your function would look like this
def GetFloorName(Room_ID, Chamber_ID):
    # Return None If Room_ID is None
    if  Room_ID is None:
        return None

    floor = []
    #split by comma and loop over all 
    for z in Room_ID.split(','):
        floor.append(sqlcall(z,Chamber_ID))
    return ','.join(floor)

#dummy sqlcall
def sqlcall(f,z):
    if z>5:
        return X
    else:
        return Y 

#apply the function on the series
df['Floor_Name'] = df.apply(lambda x:  GetFloorName(x.Room_ID, x.Chamber_ID),axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Alot This was what i was looking for